# I would like to specify a date in the condition of the function "if", how can I do that?

Tags: if-statement, pine-script

I would like to specify a date in the condition of the function "if", how can I do that?

For example, is it possible to set a condition such as "if the closing price rises by 10% within a week"?

Comment: What are you working in?

Comment: I didn't understand how this site works.
I am currently studying pinescript for tradingview.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the `close` price one week ago, you'll need to reference a bar in history. You can get the number of bars you need to reference in history using this code:

```
bars_back = (time - (time - 604800000)) / (1000 * timeframe.in_seconds(timeframe.period))
```

From there it's just comparing the condition:

```
if close / close[bars_back] > 1.1
    // do something
```

Example code:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)

bars_back = (time - (time - 604800000)) / (1000 * timeframe.in_seconds(timeframe.period))
cond = close / close[bars_back] > 1.1
plotshape(cond)
```